# Cannot change window border theme in Gnome (shell or flashback)

Tags: 16.04, gnome-classic, macbuntu

So I changed back to Ambiance from the Macbuntu theme, but the window border is still the Macbuntu one, I have looked and none of the other questions work on 16.04, so how do I change the window border back to the Ambiance one?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change window border in GNOME Flashback (Metacity) you will need to do it from terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity theme Ambiance
```